# How can I access a nested variable in batch?

Tags: batch-file

Working on a program that can draw and update a map in batch.

Currently having an issue with `Row!currentline![Column]` `Row!Currentline!CharacterCount`

This is the map draw script:

```
:DrawMap
Echo on
@echo At Draw Map>>Flow.log
set /a CurrentLine = 0
Rem ^ Clears any Lingering data for Currentline

@echo Total Lines understood by Draw map to be: !TotalLines!>>Flow.log

rem V acts as a point to return to in the loop
:DMloop1

rem V checks to see if all lines have been printed, if not continues the loop   
if !CurrentLine! LSS !TotalLines! do (

    rem V clears any pre-existing value for cycle
    Set /a Column =0

    rem V acts as a point to return to in the loop
    :DMloop2
    set charcount=Row!currentLine!CharacterCount
    @echo Charcount = !charcount!>>Flow.log
    @echo Loop Charcount value = !^!Charcount!^!>>Flow.log

    rem V checks if all characters have been printed if not continues the loop
    if !Columb! LSS !^!Charcount!^!(
        @echo Charcount loop success>>Flow.log
        @echo Loop Charcount value = !^!Charcount!^!>>Flow.log
        rem V Increases the Column count by 1
        set /a Column +=1
        set RowChar=Row!currentLine![!Column!]
        set Rowcall=!Rowchar!

        Rem Prints the Character within that space V
        @echo !%Rowcall%!
        @echo !%Rowcall%!>>Flow.log

        rem V goes back to the 2nd loop cycle
        goto DMloop2
    )

    rem V increases the line to begin printing
    set /a CurrentLine +=1

    rem V goes back to Loop1
    goto DMloop1
)
pause
goto :eof
```

The script that called this function had `EnableDelayedExpansion`.

Not sure how best to iterate over `Row!Currentline!CharacterCount` & `Row!currentline![Column]` as most means I have attempted end up in null values, including trying to have another variable hold the Literal String for the variable and try invoking as seen above but no luck.

Comment: `for /L %%b in (0,1,9) do echo var%%bA=!var%%bA!` should show you each variable's value. `set var` ditto.

Comment: @Magoo Tried this the log responce was Null. 

Code loop

`:DMloop2
for /L %%b in (0,1,!Currentline!) do (
set /a Charcount=!Row%%bCharacterCount!
)`

Gives me the responce 


`Total Lines understood by Draw map to be: 9`
`Charcount = `

within my flow logs. any idea what i may be doing wrong?

Comment: Post your code then, we cannot assist you in making something work in the context of your code, if you do not post a [mcve] of that code.

Comment: Okay @Compo was just trying to keep out some Messy code, one moment. will update.

Comment: I do not see the code @Magoo, offered in your submission, and which you've stated doesn't work. BTW, I've indented the code appropriately for reading, which certainly helps to remove the 'Messy' look.

Comment: @compo reverted the code to a previous state, prior to the change it replaced  All things bellow the `DMloop2` and  above the if statement. the `!^!charcount!^!`  was replaced to `!charcount!` within the if statement below. Also thanks for cleaning up the code Compo

Comment: Sorry, no labels and no `goto`'s within a code-block.